Redirecting incoming HTTPS traffic from one port to another without the SSL key
Is it possible to configure httpd to redirect HTTPS traffic from one host:port to another without decrypting it?
I've got HTTPS traffic coming in at port 443. Depending on the incoming SNI I'd like httpd to redirect the request to a different host:port.
Normally, I'd use a reverse proxy, but I've got one additional constraint: I cannot provide httpd with the SSL key. Is it possible for it to redirect traffic without decrypting it first?
httpd won't be able to access the host header because it's not allowed to decrypt the request.
Here's what I've got so far:
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName example.com

    SSLProxyEngine On
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyStatus On

    <Proxy *>
        Require all granted
    </Proxy>

    RequestHeader set "X-Forwarded-Proto" expr=%{REQUEST_SCHEME}
    RequestHeader set "X-Forwarded-SSL" expr=%{HTTPS}
    
    ProxyPass / https://localhost:8443/ retry=0
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8443/
</VirtualHost>

When I hit example.com on port 443, it looks like httpd is trying to process it as HTTP (plain text) traffic, and no redirection takes place.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6331371/how-to-redirect-https-to-http-without-any-ssl-certificate

You say you have HTTPS on 80, which would be very unusual and rather difficult, but then say it's on 443, which is different, although your config won't work as shown because it doesn't have SSLEngine on and a cert&key (which is your problem). In any case httpd can't do this, but nginx in stream mode or haproxy in tcp mode can peek at SNI and selectively proxy (not redirect); both have answers on serverfault and stackoverflow, but not here perhaps because those programs are not Unix-specific (nor is httpd). @aviro: today is different from 2011

@dave_thompson_085 Sorry abou tthe port 80. That was indeed a typo (which I've corrected). I'll take a look at nginx and haproxy. Thank you!

It sounds like you're essentially looking for a layer 4 load balancer/proxy. I don't know of a way to in Apache, but I've used HAProxy for this or created iptables forward rule. But if you're just passing everything to it, you may want to route directly to it instead of adding an additional hop.
